# Crystal Reports Sub reports repeating based on Parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with 4 seperate sub-reports embedded into it.
On the main report, I have a parameter to filter by group and I have it set to filter by group unless you choose All for the parameter, then it shows all groups.

```
If {?Main Group Name} = "ALL" then {Incident.Group Name} like "*"
else {Incident.Group Name} = {?Main Group Name}
```

This filter setup works fine on the individual sub reports, however if I run it selecting "all" as part of the main group, it causes the sheet to loop indefinitely and doesn't show the data properly.

The data is in all Group header 1 and group footer 1, so ideally the same page(as below) should repeat for every group.
[image: Correct view for 1 group]

When I run it for all, It runs for an abnormally long time, and has to be manually stopped, otherwise it just keeps going.  After manually stopping, I get the following.  It almost looks like it's trying to render all the groups on top of each other.

[image]
[image]

Anyone have a clue what could cause this?

Comment: In the links to the subreports, are you passing the group value or the main report parameter value?

Comment: Yes, the main group value is being passed to all the individual sub-reports.  It displays fine when running it for a single group, only when I select multipl.e

Comment: So you're definitely not passing the main report parameter value to each of the subreports?

Answer (score 0):

Where are your subreports located in the main report (group header)?  What are you doing with the record details of the main report (suppressing, I'm guessing)?  What do the record selection formulas look like, FROM the subreports?  How many tables are in the subreports?  If multi-table, are your joins correct?

I have seen occurrences when subreports have a given Record Selection, and then have links added from the main report, where the resulting subreport query is totally hosed as Crystal Reports "helps" by modifying the subreport record selection on top of what the developer intended.  True Story (a 17 second report was updated and ran for 20 hours before anyone noticed it had never finished a scheduled run).  It *sounds* (heh, in inter-text) like you don't have correct relationships set up in the subreports, and may actually have cartesean products being formed.

Where are you using your code shown in your question?  In the Record Selection?  In an @Formula?  What kind of link are you using to the subreport?  What "should" be linked to the subreports is the {Incident.Group Name} -- as that is what changes in the main report group.

If you break out the subreports, and run them individually, manually setting the {?Main Group Name} to "ALL" and then to sample group names, what is the result?  If the individual subreports still run on, you can at least watch the record counts (status bar) and when you manually kill the report, you can look at the performance information, and at the subreport Show Query.

Lastly, if you try running the main as "ALL" using a Top 10 (or 2, or whatever number you want) and then watch the subreport performance, that might give some clues.  If there are selection-hosation byproducts, this would at least limit the effects a bit.   You'd still be passing "*" to the subreport, but only doing it "N" cycles.

Sigh, and one last:  If you really want "all", you might be better served if you use something like:

```
If {?Main Group Name} = "ALL" then TRUE
else {Incident.Group Name} = {?Main Group Name}
```

Sorry to be so long... I didn't have enough time to shorten it.

OK, really, really LAST one:  If I have misunderstood your post, assumed too many disparate themes, or am just talking out of my hat:  Sorry.  Missed a meal, picked up several interruptions, and doubled up on the coffee.  I'm sure there's a smiley for that, somewhere.

Comment: The sub reports are all within Group Header 1, and each sub-report in turn has it's graph's in group header 1.

Comment: The sub reports are all within Group Header 1, and each sub-report in turn has it's graph's in group header 1.  The code listed is in the select expert, I tried altering it to your code and received the same result.

Comment: Sorry - had to re-comment:  I have a little confusion:  ARE you grouping by "Group" in the main (awkward choice of column names)?  When you select "ALL", what is _supposed_ to happen in the Main Report?  Is it supposed to be a roll-up (summary) in the main (and should the charts show everything)?  *IN MY MIND*, I am seeing your rpt group on individual records (in main) and running subs on EVERY RECORD.  Can you add some column overlays on the charts to see what the report is "seeing"?

Comment: The main report is grouped by group name, and all the graphs are in Group Header1.  The goal is to have the first screenshot above for each independent group.  So I could get 4 graphs per group, not a total

Answer (score 0):

[Inserting add'l answer, as it is distinct enough to warrant it's own entry.]

I think I understand the Group Header/Foot Charts.
Did you try running Main as a Top 10 to limit the # groups?
How big is the (chart) record set?

AND, is the report set up for asynchronous queries?

What IS going on in the subreports: 
Complex query?
Simple query?
Suppressing all Details and just showing the Chart?
Going to a different table/database?
Table joins?

Run for "Top 10" Groups in main, wait until it ends, then check for the Main and each chart sub (for at least a few groups):

```
Report / Performance Information: 
    Total Number of Records -- (Main should be "Top 10" )
    Performance Timing:  
       Run the Query, 
       Read Database Records, 
       Time to Format All Charts 
          or 
       Time to Format 1st Page.
```

If you have several millions of records, even with "top", it could take a while to read and calculate the top.  If you are calling charting, even tho' it is for a single Group per chart, if the subreport still has to apply a linked query, parse millions of records, perform add'l calculations, create a chart (that still accounts for all records), etc., it can just be a long time running.

You may find that a small "All" Top "n" will show a lot of time being spent behind the scenes, and that allowing the whole report to run that the add'l Comparison of Ticket Counts is displayed.  And if not, we can look at that later (mainly by opening up the corpse and looking inside).

I am trying to ascertain regular behaviour, and I can't get a requirements doc for review.  I can only make assumptions and ask questions and make suggestions.